NWChem gives weird esp charges
So I am trying to produce partial charges for a variety of geometries of many polar solvents. In order to test the methodology and to know what to expect, I am using water as a starting system.
The idea was to generate a lot of geometries using a metropolis algorithm and to use the NWChem to compute RESP charges. I don't yet have a script to write the constraints for the ESP calculations of the NWChem in order to produce the RESP charges but, preliminarily, I just had the script use the ESP charges, just to see what it looked like.
It turns out that the charges were a mess. In many structures there were positive charges on the oxygen. I mean, I knew that ESP charges require restraints in order to be physically coherent and, at first, that is what I thought was responsible for such a weird behavior. But then I wasn't sure this was about RESP anymore. The molecule was water, for Boltzmann's sake. Restraints applied to the ESP charges on water would be minimal.
In order to analyze the problem I took two structures. One of them is the water molecule optimized, the other is a water molecule optimized with a slight 0.01 Angstrom variation in one of the coordinates of the second hydrogen. The disparity in the ESP charges is humongous. This seems to indicate that small changes in inter-atomic distance can produce grotesque variations in the partial charges across the molecule. Is such a non-local behavior expected? Is this a documented property of ESP charges? I am at a loss.
What could be the cause of such a stark variation in partial charges accross two geometries which are so very similar? Is is expected that strange charge distributions, such as positive partial charges on the oxygen, occur in geometries which are distant from the minimum by small variations?
I am not proficient on NWChem, I got my hands on it because after a short search on the internet I found that it had native ways of carrying out ESP partial charges computation and had support for a simple RESP block of instruction which could be written right at the input file. A lot of ab initio electronic structure codes out I stumbled upon, albeit very well recommended, had to rely on complicated external software for even the simplest of ESP computations and each of these external tools had to be compiled and mastered. At the time, it seemed like a waste, since NWChem was so promising, but now I'm willing to take in new recommendations in order to solve this problem, provided these issues are a matter of the NWChem alone, and not a problem of partial charge calculations in general.
So my question is:
Is this an expected behavior for partial charges computation?
If this is not an expected behavior, I very much would want to know how can I use NWChem to compute charges appropriately, since I'll have to fix my computation so that I can do my other polar solvents.
I already pre-emptively thank any kind soul willing and knowledgeable enough to drag me out of the pit. Any information on the problem is valid. Maybe these types of computations simply are like that and there is nothing to be done. That is very much a valid answer. I just need to understand what is going on.
Technical Difficulty
I was trying to post the question with the input and output files I used, but the system did not allow me to post them, saying that my post had extrapolated the 30k words or so limit. I'm not sure what to do, how can I send the output/input files in order for you to look?

+1 but can you please reduce the post down to just one question, as described here? I don't want your question to be closed with the "needs more focus" reason, but if there's more than one question mark in the question, then it needs more focus. We prefer one laser-focused question.

@NikeDattani-NoFreeTime Aye o>

Related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1439/what-are-the-types-of-charge-analysis/1443#1443

Then again: the electrostatic potential of any continuous charge distribution remains unchanged if one adds any harmonic function whatsoever to the distribution. The electrostatic potential of three point charges will not underdetermine their signs and magnitudes THAT wildly -- but it's not crazy to imagine they're still pretty underdetermined!

This is certainly not the expected behavior of ESP derived charges, whether the RESP version or some other fitting scheme. Perhaps you can write a .wfn file and then the Multiwfn program will allow you to derive a number of different ESP fitted charges.
